# Understanding django transactions

Tags: django, transactions

I have a little question concerning understanding *with transaction.atomic()*. If I want to create bulk objects withing a single transaction like this

```
emails = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
for email in emails: 
    Users.objects.create(email=email)
```

1) The above code creates and executes a query on each iteration. So the datetimefield will be different for each email. Is this correct?

However if i use:

```
with transaction.atomic(): 
    emails = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
    for email in emails: 
        Users.objects.create(email=email)
```

The reason I ask is I have a background celery task which creates notifications for multiple users via loop iteration, I find it not efficient. So I'm wondering would it be executed in a single transaction and if it is, is the datetimefield for each notification created within the transaction will be equal ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Model.objects.bulk_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create):

> This method inserts the provided list of objects into the database in
>   an efficient manner (generally only 1 query, no matter how many
>   objects there are):

---

```
Users.objects.bulk_create([
    Users(email=email) for email in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
])
```

Comment: Is this the same as using via iteration with transaction I described ?

Comment: @skzd, No they will be different. As quoted, it generally run in 1 query.

Comment: So adding transaction statement won't generate 1 query ?

Comment: @skzd, using transaction, it will generate multiple statement with surround `begin` and `commit` statement. You can check it using `django.db.connections.queries`. (in debug mode)

Comment: @falsetru In fact for large number of emails there will be multiple queries in the `bulk_create`.  It splits the list of objects by chunks.

Answer (score 1):

Datetime field will be different for each user in both cases.  If you want the same datetime for each User then you have to pass it manually:

```
with transaction.atomic():
    emails = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    now = timezone.now()
    Users.objects.bulk_create([
        Users(email=email, date_joined=now) for email in emails
    ])
```